# "Salvare" for "save a file"? Or "scaricare"? Or something else?

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice

I'm developing a computer program (for learning Italian) for which I need the Italian equivalent of "save as text file". User clicks on a button and a certain file is saved to his computer. Google translates as: "salvare come file di testo". Is "salvare" correct in this sense?  I'm only seen it in the sense of saving someone from, say, drowning. But I mean it in the sense of "downloading" the file. Except "downloading" is not quite right, since it's in the program, not on the Internet. But I'll use "scaricare" if that's best. Maybe "scaricare come .txt file"?  Or, what would be better?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really fully correct, but it's the standard translation nonetheless.

Comment: OP, "salvare" has many more meanings, among which the one you're looking for, which is recorded even by traditionalist dictionaries: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/salvare/ (search "informatica").

Answer (score 9):

'Salvare' is  correct, 'salvare come file di testo' is 'save as text file'.

'Scaricare' is 'download', not 'save'.